# Denying all access to specific table of SQL server 2008 except select ?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

How to denying all access to specific table of SQL server 2008 except select?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the four easiest ways are:

- You can set the user account / group to have [db_datareader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and
  [db_denydatawriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188308%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).
- You could allow the user to only have access
  to Views.
- You could grant the user [select only access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx).
- You could grant the user only execute access to Stored Procedures.

Comment: I can't make the user db_datareader as he should be able to modify other tables. I added table to securable for user and provided select access but he is able to modify table :( . What I did finally was to manually deny all access except select,control and view definition. I left the contrl and view definition unchecked but checked (grant) select permission.